highlight x-axis on x value condition
High everybody!
I have a series with constant time step e.g:
2009/07/13,120
2009/07/14,120
2009/07/15,120
but sometimes some steps missed:
2009/07/16,120
2009/07/19,180
var inputdata = "2024/03/28 16:00,8.3\n"+"2024/03/28 16:30,8.8\n"+"2024/03/28 17:00,9.2\n"+"2024/03/28 18:30,9.8\n"+"2024/03/28 19:00,9.0\n"+"2024/03/28 19:30,7.2\n"

    Dygraph.onDOMready(function onDOMready() {      
      g = new Dygraph(
            document.getElementById("div_g"),
inputdata
, {
              legend: 'always',
              visibility: [true],
              colors:['red'],  
              labels :["date","IN"],
                series: {
                "IN": {
                  strokeWidth: 1
                },
              }
            }
          );
    });

Can I highlight missed area?
Is it possible to expand missed area?

We'd be happy to help you highlight missing areas in your visualization, but to give the most specific advice, please share a [mcve] of your code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
